# What will be the impact on SEO if we remove our SSL certificate (url become http instead of https)?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, https, security-certificate, ranking

For some weird reason the content accessed though our domains is returned via SSL HTTPS  on all domains pointing to the server.

`https://domain.com` leads to our website, with a proper SSL certificate (so, no warning).

`https://domain2.com`, is also hosted on our server but without a SSL certificate This leads to a warning message and if accepted continues to the content of this domain.

The problem is that any search for our keywords in Google shows "fake websites" on top of ours and with the warning et al.

It seems unsolvable so we are thinking about turning SSL off. I'm just afraid of losing whatever indexing we have. How can I avoid that?

Comment: If it's without the SSL certificate, should it not be http://domain2.com?

Comment: I think this needs to be explained a little more clearly before it's possible to give a useful answer. For example, have you looked at why the 2nd domain is forwarding to the first? By losing "indexing", do you mean content being de-indexed, or losing rank?

Comment: second domain redirects to the first because the first is the only SSL domain hosted on this server. (that's what the sys admin told me at least).  By losing "indexing", i meant losing rank.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an video by Matt Cutts discussing a similar subject about people going from HTTP to HTTPS I presume the same would hold true going the other way. But since the host and path name of the pages are not changing I don't expect you should lose rankings if you go down it'll most likely be Google re-indexing your pages.

> **Can switching to HTTPS harm ranking?**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeFo4ytOk8M

Answer (score 0):

It might have some impact on your rankings if the HTTPS page is indexed within Google.

You should be using rel canonical your pages on the HTTP so Google believes that HTTP is the master protocol.

A quick fix for this is to purchase another SSL Cert for the 2nd domain, they only cost around £10 for a year.